Inside house water pressure drops when sprinkler is on
We have a well which is supplying water to the house and sprinkler system. Before water enters the house, there is a water softener. The sprinkler system does not use treated water, so it is not connected to the water softener. The water pressure is normal until the sprinkler system starts watering. We are still able to take a shower, but the water pressure is reduced.  When watering is done, pressure goes up to the initial level. I wonder if there is something that can be done so that the sprinkler use does not affect the house pressure.

You are exactly correct, that is how it works.   Now if the pressure drop is excessive, there could be a break in a sprinkler supply pipe.  However you did not say that.

Welcome.  What is your actual question?  Are you asking if this is normal?

you get a similar pressure drop when you flush a toilet

Your pressure regulator is broken, replace it.

You aren't getting enough flow into the house to sustain pressure at that much usage.
Make sure valves are fully open. If there's a pressure regulator, check that. If you are on a well, check that your pump is producing enough water.
[I see you said you're on a well. You may want a stronger pump, if the well can sustain that flow. Or you may need to check the pressure tank and related components to make sure you are getting the intended pressure.]
Suggestion: Try partly closing the valve that runs to the sprinkler system,  reducing it's maximum water consumption. You can run longer cycles to compensate, if desired.  Or cut it up into more zones and run them sequentially rather than simultaneously. Either will leave more pressure available for the rest of the house. (I use a zoned timer even with a simple above-ground system, to manage needs in different parts of the yard and because some of my sprinklers require a certain amount of pressure to work well )

Thank you for your reply. I do not have a pressure regulator on the sprinkler line, only the sprinkler head are pressure regulated. If I install a regulator on the sprinkler line, before all the valves, do you have a recommendation?
